# Grid view showing single image many times

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have this function call Photogrid() that is being called by storePhotos() which fetches images from firebase storage using snapshots and the passes values to Photogrid().

```
     storePhotos() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: imagesSnapshots,
        builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    print("we are here");
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 1000,
                      child: PhotoGrid(
                          imageLink: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["link"],
                          images: [snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["link"]],
                          ownerName:
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["owner"]),
                    );
                  }),
                )
              : Container();
        }));
  }
```

The problem is that Photogrid() is showing only a single image all the time. How can I iterate through all the images.

```
class PhotoGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageLink;
  final String ownerName;
  final List<String> images;

  const PhotoGrid(
      {required this.imageLink, required this.ownerName, required this.images});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                ),
                itemCount: images.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => RouteTwo(
                                    image: imageLink, owner: ownerName)));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(images[index]))),
                      ));
                },
              )),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try debug/printing the links to make sure you are getting different links?

Comment: Yes, the links are different as they are get in storePhotos(). But when used in Gridview, only one index (the first one) is being displayed many times.

Comment: try with use key on widget, you can use image link as value key for this. if you use duplicate link it will trough error, BTW using link as key just to check duplication here.

Comment: Sorry but couldn't get your idea